# Giving a custom script root permissions

Tags: linux, scripting, linux-mint, startup

I have a backup drive that is Truecrypt Encrypted. I'd like to automnt this drive so I can automate backups when in the office. I am using Linux Mint 12 x64bit

I wrote a script that runs successfully with Sudo to mount the encrypted drive.

However, I can not get the drive to mount automatically...

I tried entering the script into rc.local, but that doesn't work.

So I tried editing the sudoers file (thinking I could enter this script into the startup applications area for Mint):

```
username ALL= NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/bakmnt.sh
```

*username is replaced with my real my username in the sudoers file

Still, when I try to run the script without sudo, I get:

```
Error: Failed to obtain administrator privileges.
```

I'm out of ideas, googling around seems to be an issue with Truecrypt..but I still come up empty for a solution. Any thoughts out there?

thanks for reading!!

Comment: Did you try putting the drive in /etc/fstab?

Comment: I did not, as I understand it, there is no way to specify a password so the truecrypt partition will not mount under fstab.

Comment: so how do you supply password to mount it?

Comment: "Still, when I try to run the script without sudo, I get..." if you added yourself to the sudoers, you should be using sudo. I'm confused.

Comment: @yarek, it's part of the bash script I wrote.

Comment: @Patrick There is the startup applications section I was trying to use, as rc.local was not working. In startup applications, I believe I still need a way to give the script root permissions. So, I added a NOPASSWD section to SUDOERS for this particular script, see the section in my original post above what "Still, when I try to run the script without sudo"...as I understand it, I should be able to run the script as root, without a password (i.e. no sudo)...perhaps I don't understand the sudoers file?

Comment: So are you saying it's the sudo without password that's not working?

Comment: @Awhitehatter you have to prefix the command with sudo now. So you would run `sudo /usr/local/bin/bakmnt.sh`. It wont ask for a password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using sudoers is crock upon hack upon kludge; don't do that.  rc.local (or a separate file in init.d) is the correct place to do this.  Capture the output of your script when run from there and determine why it is failing.  That should give you information you need to fix the script so that it works from rc.local.

Comment: Okay, I accept that. Any guesses where the output would log for rc.local? It isn't working and I can find a log for it.

Comment: rc.local is run as a sh script, so you can do output redirection in there; bakmnt.sh > /tmp/foobar 2>&1

Comment: Bingo!!! I didn't realize you that rc.local ran as sh script, very cool. The problem was a permissions issue with my key file. Fixed that and we are all set...thanks a million!!